# Xpath trouble on Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath

So, I'm trying to creade a code to automatic fill some research queries at my work, to save time and to exercise Python (I've only been trying python for a week). While using Selenium, I can't seen to get the Xpath to work properly, especially on the last Three Items. I don't know where I got the /table or the  /div/div on Xpath, But as I was editing the code it seems that only the one with /table works. I don't know why I can't get it on the page anymore or why it was even there, since i'm doing the same method.

I'm actually having trouble on the last three buttons, I can't seem to know where and why. Those are the ones that I was having trouble, the first one works but the last one doesnt, when I try to extract the full xpath I get the div/div but when i use the /table/tbody it works for the first of these buttons but not for the latter ones. Can someone shed a light on what i'm missing.

```
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/input').click()
time.sleep(1)
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input').click()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/input').click()


navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/button').click()
```

THE FULL CODE:

````
from selenium import webdriver
navegador = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
navegador.get("https://pesquisasatisfacao.saude.rj.gov.br/Unidade/criar-emergencia/5955637")
time.sleep(1)

# Caracteristicas paciente.
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/input').click()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/input').click()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/input').click()

import time
time.sleep(1) 

navegador.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
time.sleep(1)

#Atenção e respeito dos profissionais
#/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/input

navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#Tempo de espera
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#Limpeza da unidade
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#Avaliação das instalaçoes
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#atendimento da recepção
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#Classificação de Risco
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#Atendimento da Enfermagem
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#Atendimento Médico
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]/div/input').click()
#Exames em geral
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[1]/div/input').click()

navegador.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1200);")
time.sleep(3)

navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/input').click()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/input').click()
time.sleep(1)
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input').click()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/input').click()


navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/button').click()

#/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[3]/div[1]/div[1]/input
#/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[3]/div[1]/div[1]/input
#/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[3]/div[1]/div[1]/label```
````

Comment: can you add time delay between every clicks.

Comment: Your xpath's are absolute which means they are brittle. Please share relevant HTML code or steps to find the web element. If you could, try to use relative xpath.

Comment: How can I do that?